# What would be needed for the U.S. to abolish or reform the electoral college?

Tags: united-states, electoral-college

What would it take to reform the U.S. Presidential Elections such that either

- The President is elected by popular vote, abolishing the electoral college completely, or
- every state is mandated to allocate their electors proportionally?

The former would guarantee that the candidate with the most votes wins the presidency; the second would not completely guarantee it but would make it far less likely for the electoral college vote winner to be different from the popular vote winner.

What would be the procedure to introduce such a change?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48567/discussion-on-question-by-gerrit-what-would-be-needed-for-the-u-s-to-abolish-or).

Comment: @ SJuan76  I think that using a county-by-county method is a legitimate way to proportionally allocate electors if the individual states are required to do so.  Otherwise, we're right back in the "Tyranny of the Majority".

Comment: @MichaelJ. this conversation has been moved to chat.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Amendment

The electoral system is defined in the constitution ([Article II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Section_1:_President_and_Vice_President) and [Amendment XII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)), so to completely abolish it would require a constitutional amendment. That can technically be done in a couple different ways (see [Article V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Five_of_the_United_States_Constitution)), but in practice requires two thirds of congress and three fourths of the states, so it's very difficult. Still, [such amendments have been proposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Electoral_College#Efforts_to_abolish_or_reform), [the most recent being filed today](http://www.latimes.com/politics/essential/la-pol-ca-essential-politics-updates-boxer-files-longshot-bill-to-scrap-the-1479234745-htmlstory.html).

#### Re-allocation

Your second suggestion (or something like it) is much more feasible. The [National Popular Vote Interstate Compact](http://www.nationalpopularvote.com/) (NPVIC) is a state law that awards all of a state's electors to the winner of the national popular vote, but only once enough states have joined the compact to make an electoral majority.

Article II stipulates that legislature of each state direct the selection of the state's electors, so they're well within their power to change that mechanism, and the NPVIC only requires enough states to represent a majority of the electoral college, which is a much lower bar than the three fourths for an amendment.

At the moment, it has 165 of the 270 electoral votes needed to take effect. However, crossing the 270 threshold will require some states that are currently Republican-controlled. As [only Democrats have ever been burned by the Electoral College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_elections_in_which_the_winner_lost_the_popular_vote#Comparative_table_of_elections), [Republicans don't have a lot of incentive to change the status quo](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-a-plan-to-circumvent-the-electoral-college-is-probably-doomed/). However, [most Americans do support a national popular vote for president](http://www.nationalpopularvote.com/polls), so perhaps the political will is there.

Comment: Four things. The first is your amendment process could also happen through a Constitutional Convention, although that's much harder.  Second, if you abolish the college, the states would have significant cleanup to do as well, which would require state constitutional and legal changes

Comment: Three, it's not enough for most states to just vote in the Compact like some form of legislation.  They would need to amend their state Constitutions, if electors are included therein, or rescind laws like this Virginia one http://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title24.2/chapter2/section24.2-202/

Comment: Four, take effect doesn't mean across the entire US.  It would only apply to those states that agreed to it. And it's more of a gentlemen's agreement at that.  The state and constitutional changes in point 3 are more important.

Comment: @KDog If it applies in a states whose sum of electoral votes exceeds 270, it would be irrelevant what the rest does, or?

Comment: @KDog 1) I noted and linked the details of the amendment process. I think it appropriate for brevity in the answer to focus on the only way that process has actually ever happened.

Comment: @KDog 3) Bills for the NPVIC have been at least introduced in all but six states, so clearly there is a feasible mechanism in most cases. Is there actually a state constitution that specifies the elector selection method? Would that not contradict the US constitution's requirement that the legislatures decide?

Comment: @KDog & gerrit 4) It takes effect when the members represent a majority of the EC. That means it would decide the winner, regardless of what the other states do.

Comment: How do we bring this to chat?  I want to explore that last point by P1, and I believe the state legislatures are the ones that decide on the State Constitutions, so therefore my point about state constitutions.  I know Virginia doesn't cover there.

Comment: Massachusetts has electors in theirs.

Comment: @KDog We're close to getting the notification to move to chat anyway. MA uses the word “elector” in their constitution, but it looks like it's used as a synonym for “voter,” not in reference to presidential electors. Also, they have passed the NPVIC: https://malegislature.gov/Bills/186/H4156/

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Ok, so maybe it's legislative cleanup rather than Constitutional cleanup.  But about the pact, are you saying that as a rule if they get to 270, all those states would vote en mass for the same candidate based upon the popular vote rather than state by state?

Comment: @KDog Yes, that's the notion of the compact.

Comment: Because that would potentially disenfranchise some Pact states entirely if they were on the losing side.

Comment: @Brythan That's why I said “currently.” I don't think it's likely that a state that voted Trump has the political will among the people to undo the status quo that favored their choice. Also, this has to be done by legislatures and governors, and those are Republican by a significant majority. The path to 233 goes through several GOP governors and GOP-controlled houses. Then, as you say, it takes at least a couple large, purple states beyond that. I rephrased to reflect the GOP control, but not claim “very” Republican.

Comment: I don't think this Pact would withstand 14th and 15th Amendment challenges.

Comment: Unless all 50 states were in it.

Comment: @KDog It would lessen the power of the state governments of the non-member states, but it would not disenfranchise the voters because they still contribute to the national tally. They would be just as enfranchised as every other voter, which is of course the point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48565/discussion-between-k-dog-and-p1h3r1e3d13).

Comment: The thing with the National Pact is that it cannot bind a state to stay in it indefinitely. A state could unilaterally decide to leave the pact.

Comment: "Would that not contradict the US constitution's requirement that the legislatures decide?"  No.  There's actual [precedent](http://www.scotusblog.com/case-files/cases/arizona-state-legislature-v-arizona-independent-redistricting-commission/) on that.  Arizona voters changed their state constitution to remove redistricting power from the legislature.  The Supreme Court upheld.  As the language is the same here, the same rationale would almost certainly apply.

Comment: @eques And theywould leave, the moment that it caused a state to cast their electors in a way that didn't match the voters in their state.

Comment: The compact now reaches 172 electoral votes: https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-movement-to-skip-the-electoral-college-is-picking-up-steam/

Answer (score 0):

Both Options would require a constitutional amendment.  As it currently stands the National Popular Vote Compact is not abolishing the system, but the states agreeing to the rules of allocation for their states electors.

Completely switching to a National Vote would require an amendment to the constitution to become valid.  This is less tenable than the compact as it requires 3/4ths of states to ratify the amendment (after both houses pass it in 2/3rds majority no less) or a constitutional convention of states (Never been done before).   This is also true for require proportional representation as the states each have a right to establish their own voting system and are free to choose how they allocate electors, be it proprortional representation (Maine and Nebraska), Winner Take All (everyone else), or Candidates compete in a match of Calvinball to the Death (No one ever, thank God!).

Comment: Final alternative would save a lot of money.

Comment: @gerrit - I'm not saying I won't watch the game day match with as much furvor as the Superbowl (maybe even more), I'm just saying on the ranking "basis for a system of government" it ranks below "Random Women, living in lakes, handing out swords."